# Restfb - Why when I fetch my admined groups the app throws OAuthException: (#200) Permissions error (code 200, subcode null)

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

I'm programming in Java and I'm trying to fetch all the Facebook groups which I am the admin.

Thus, I've created an app called "Secrets" in Facebook Graph API Explorer and 
checked all the permissions when I generated my ACCESS TOKEN.

For my Java app I'm using the library: restfb-1.18.0

The weird thing is that I'm getting the list of my admined groups but then
the app throws the exception: OAuthException: (#200) Permissions error (code 200, subcode null)

I don't know why i get this error.

Here is my code snippet:

```
String accessTokenGraphApiExplorer = "...";

FacebookClient fbClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessTokenGraphApiExplorer,Version.VERSION_2_0);



int counter = 0;
final String MY_FEEDS_PROPERTY = "me/groups";

String param = "groups,name";

Connection<Group> result = fbClient.fetchConnection(MY_FEEDS_PROPERTY, Group.class, Parameter.with("fields", param));

try {
    for (List<Group> groupPage : result) {
        for (Group group : groupPage) {
            System.out.println(group.getName());
            counter++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("# of Groups I admin: " + counter);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Why are you requesting `groups` in your field list? You are requesting data _from_ the `groups` endpoint of the user node already, so what is that even supposed to refer to? It would mean that you are asking for a field `groups` _of_ each of the individual group nodes you get back. Group nodes don’t have an additional `groups` field or edge below them.

Comment: The reason i'm using "groups" in the fields because when I used it in Graph API Exlporer, it gave me the result I wanted: only the groups on which I'm the admin.

Now how this exception can be solved?

Comment: Okay, that seems to be some undocumented magic then, can’t find anything about that in the docs. // Where exactly does it throw the exception? It looks like you have only the loop over the result wrapped in try/catch, not the actual API call itself - so does it come from within the try/catch block, or is it an uncaught exception from the API call itself before, that simply bubbles up until it shows somewhere?

Comment: The reason I add the try/catch is because in the main for loop, when it tries to go to the next iteration, it throws the OAuthException: (#200) Permissions error (code 200, subcode null), 

The main for loop indicates the paging, where each of the paging contains 25 groupPages.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with pagination then. It throws errors in GAE already, when I add a `limit` parameter (to force pagination to happen) - `me/groups?fields=id,name&limit=2` works, when I add the `groups` field, I get a “permissions error” there as well. Guess you can file a bug report and ask them if this is gonna get fixed, https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs - or remove the `groups` field, add `administrator` instead (that will contain true/false) and filter out what you need on your end. (That does not appear to throw the same error, pagination with that works in GAE.)

Comment: I truly appreciate it!

One last question, how can I force that it will give me all the groups where 
administrator = true ?
I've tried doing me/groups?fields=id,name&administrator=true but it still gives me all the groups, including those I'm not the admin.

Comment: You can’t, that’s why I said filter it based on that field on your end …